# How can I select a checkbox based on the class of a parent node?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a table with checkboxes as the value in one of the columns. Certain rows have a specific class `ignore`, and I want to select checkboxes that don't have that class on their enclosing row. Dummy example below:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="ignore">
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="table_select" value="1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="table_select" value="2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="table_select" value="3"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

So I would want to check the boxes in rows 2 and 3. I'm using a general `:checkbox` selector now, but am not sure how to combine `parent()` and `.class` to go up the hierarchy then back down.

Comment: Would the `:not(…)` selector be what you're looking for? `tr:not(.ignore) [type="checkbox"]:checked`, I assume?

Comment: ↑ without the `:checked` as the OP wants to check them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```js
$('tr:not(.ignore) :checkbox').prop('checked', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="ignore">
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="table_select" value="1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="table_select" value="2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="table_select" value="3"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. I was starting at checkbox and trying to work way up instead of filtering down from the row.

Comment: What's difference between `:checkbox` and `input[type="checkbox"]`?

Comment: `:checkbox` equals `[type="checkbox"]`, so they're basically the same.